# Songs by popular bands

Tags: crosswords

[image]

#### Across

**1.** Gap
**6.** *(See 81 Across)*
**10.** Mixture
**15.** ___ la vista
**16.** For Luis, to love
**17.** It's negative
**18.** Mr. Welles
**19.** Give up
**20.** It's not their fault, but ours
**21.** A song by Kiss?
**24.** For
**25.** Run away from 38 Across, perhaps
**26.** AT&T subsidiary
**29.** Knowledge regulatory agcy.
**32.** Requests
**35.** Bud
**38.** Mark of hesitation
**39.** Mr. Wiesel
**41.** Principle
**44.** Angina med
**46.** A song by Green Day?
**49.** ___-cop
**50.** Back-breaking device
**51.** Mr. Cartman
**52.** Voguish
**53.** 'Net expression of incredulity
**55.** Soft cheese
**57.** Unexceptional
**58.** Mr. Sutcliffe
**60.** A source of 50 Across
**63.** Secrecy pact: abbr.
**65.** A song by Spinal Tap?
**73.** Version-control tool
**75.** Earth, in fantasy
**76.** Manchester United forward
**77.** Protection, in crosswordese
**78.** One who regrets, in crosswordese
**79.** Mr. Meese
**80.** January events, often
**81.** *(with 6 Across)* A song by No Doubt?
**82.** Since, in Seville

#### Down

**1.** Chinese premier
**2.** String instrument
**3.** Secty., e.g.
**4.** Crouch
**5.** Catchphrase
**6.** Phenacyl chloride
**7.** … ___ a man with …
**8.** Candidate Ralph
**9.** King's thing
**10.** Wide band
**11.** Stake
**12.** Group of people in a logic puzzle
**13.** Mil. region
**14.** IP lookup structure
**22.** Often ornamental plant
**23.** Uni hangout
**27.** Mr. Goetz
**28.** Forked area
**29.** Video game
**30.** Articulate
**31.** Mortgage
**33.** Islands
**34.** Huff
**36.** Some
**37.** A long way
**40.** Approx. values
**42.** Org. giving 29 Down "E"
**43.** Peter the Great, for example
**45.** It may be of art or reference
**47.** Mother
**48.** In arrears
**54.** Form a row
**56.** Emended
**59.** Employment
**61.** 42 Down target
**62.** Udacity founder
**64.** 17 Across goes here
**66.** Skip
**67.** Tangle
**68.** Same, in crosswordese
**69.** Not
**70.** ___ things?
**71.** Dame Lyons
**72.** M. Descartes
**73.** Poor
**74.** Garland

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The twist to this puzzle is that the OP has been a bit sneaky with the wording of the four themed clues here (21A, 46A, 65A and 81/6A). In each case, we are *not* looking for an actual 'song by' one of the four named groups (i.e. *not* the name of a track released by these bands). Instead, we need to find:

> a set of words which can be positioned **beside** (**by**) the band name to form a longer **phrase**. These are:
>
>  KISS **UP TO THE TEACHER**
>  **TUESDAY IS SOYLENT** GREEN DAY
>  **SOMETHING IN HER** SPINAL TAP
>  NO DOUBT **IN MY MIND**
>
>  (To be honest, I am not entirely sure of the significance behind the Spinal Tap one - it may be a quote of which I am unaware - but all the letters fit!)

Here's the completed grid:

> [image: Solved grid]

And clue-by-clue, with additional explanations for the more obscure answers:

> **Across**
>  1. Gap **CHASM**
>  6. (See 81 Across) **[*IN MY* MIND](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no%20doubt%20in%20someone%27s%20mind)**
>  10. Mixture **SALAD**
>  15. ___ la vista **HASTA**
>  16. For Luis, to love **AMAR**
>  17. It's negative **ANION**
>  18. Mr. Welles **ORSON**
>  19. Give up **CEDE**
>  20. It's not their fault, but ours **STARS**
>  21. A song by Kiss? **UP TO THE TEACHER**
>  24. For **PRO**
>  25. Run away from 38 Across, perhaps **RMA** (‘Refusing Medical Attention’ – think ‘ER’ as in ‘Emergency Room’)
>  26. AT&T subsidiary **[SBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBC_Telecom)**
>  29. Knowledge regulatory agcy. **[TFL](https://tfl.gov.uk/info-for/taxis-and-private-hire/licensing/learn-the-knowledge-of-london)** (Think ‘*The* Knowledge’…)
>  32. Requests **ASKS**
>  35. Bud **FAM** (close friend)
>  38. Mark of hesitation **ER**
>  39. Mr. Wiesel **[ELIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elie_Wiesel)**
>  41. Principle **TENET**
>  44. Angina med **NITRO**
>  46. A song by Green Day? **[TUESDAY IS SOYLENT](https://johnrieber.com/2020/04/13/how-green-day-got-its-name-this-cult-movie-monday-is-a-sci-fi-pop-culture-classic/)**
>  49. ___-cop **[RENT A](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rent-a-cop)**
>  50. Back-breaking device **STRAW**
>  51. Mr. Cartman **ERIC**
>  52. Voguish **IN**
>  53. 'Net expression of incredulity **SMH**
>  55. Soft cheese **BRIE**
>  57. Unexceptional **MEH**
>  58. Mr. Sutcliffe **[STU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stu_Sutcliffe)**
>  60. A source of 50 Across **OAT**
>  63. Secrecy pact: abbr. **NDA**
>  65. A song by Spinal Tap? **SOMETHING IN HER**
>  73. Version-control tool **[BLAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control)**
>  75. Earth, in fantasy **[ARDA](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Arda)**
>  76. Manchester United forward **[TOONE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ella_Toone)**
>  77. Protection, in crosswordese **AEGIS**
>  78. One who regrets, in crosswordese **RUER**
>  79. Mr. Meese **[EDWIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Meese)**
>  80. January events, often **DIETS**
>  81. (with 6 Across) A song by No Doubt? **[IN MY *MIND*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no%20doubt%20in%20someone%27s%20mind)**
>  82. Since, in Seville **DESDE**
>
>  **Down**
>  1. Chinese premier **[CHOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhou_Enlai)**
>  2. String instrument **HARP**
>  3. Secty., e.g. **ASST**
>  4. Crouch **STOOP**
>  5. Catchphrase **MANTRA**
>  6. Phenacyl chloride **MACE**
>  7. … ___ a man with … **I MET**
>  8. Candidate Ralph **NADER**
>  9. King's thing **[DREAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Have_a_Dream)**
>  10. Wide band **SASH**
>  11. Stake **ANTE**
>  12. Group of people in a logic puzzle **LIARS**
>  13. Mil. Region **[AOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_responsibility)**
>  14. IP lookup structure **[DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)**
>  22. Often ornamental plant **HOSTA**
>  23. Uni hangout **CAF** (short for ‘cafeteria)
>  27. Mr. Goetz **[BERNIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1984_New_York_City_Subway_shooting)**
>  28. Forked area **CROTCH**
>  29. Video game **TETRIS**
>  30. Articulate **FLUENT**
>  31. Mortgage **LIEN**
>  33. Islands **KEYS**
>  34. Huff **SNIT**
>  36. Some **ANY**
>  37. A long way **MILE**
>  40. Approx. values **ESTS**
>  42. Org. giving 29 Down "E" **[ESRB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entertainment_Software_Rating_Board)**
>  43. Peter the Great, for example **TSAR**
>  45. It may be of [art](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/term%20of%20art) or [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terms_of_reference) **TERM**
>  47. Mother **[DAM](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dam#:%7E:text=%3A%20the%20female%20parent%20of%20a,dam)**
>  48. In arrears **OWING**
>  54. Form a row **HOE**
>  56. Emended **EDITED**
>  59. Employment **USAGE**
>  61. 42 Down target **ATARI**
>  62. Udacity founder **THRUN**
>  64. 17 Across goes here **ANODE**
>  66. Skip **OMIT**
>  67. Tangle **MESS**
>  68. Same, in crosswordese **[IDEM](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idem)**
>  69. Not **[NARY](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nary)**
>  70. ___ things? **HOW’S**
>  71. Dame Lyons **[ENID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enid_Lyons)**
>  72. M. Descartes **RENE**
>  73. Poor **BAD**
>  74. Garland **LEI**